# "IS NOT TRUE" with Rails 3 query or meta_where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

What I need is probably very simple:

`Table.where('field is not true')`

but I can't figure how this is done with Rails 3 query interface, and probably with [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where).  The problem is that while ":field.not_eq => nil" translates properly to "IS NOT NULL", ":field.not_eq => true" becomes "!= 1", which is clearly not the same as "IS NOT TRUE" (mysql and postgresql extension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no booleans in mysql, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html

> BOOL, BOOLEAN
>
> These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true:

As you see booleans are always tinyints which translate into 1 or 0, this is why rails will create "field != 1"  instead of field is not true.

Not sure about postgresql through.

Comment: This is not about mysql types, this is about the operator "<field> IS <boolean>", which is certainly present in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not Otherwise, I would gladly accept a more standard SQL solution that would filter out boolean fields which are not true.  Seems to be quite simple.

Comment: I might misunderstood you a little bit. In mysql `1` is the same as `true` After some testing i came to the conclusion that: `field IS true` gives the same results as `field is 1` and `field = 1` and `field = true` the same with the is not operator `field IS NOT TRUE`, `field != 1` and `field != true`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Your tests probably didn't include NULL values.  "is not true" means "not exacly equals true, including null", while "!= 1" means "whatever not evaluates to 1, but not null".  The "IS [NOT]" operator gives a false impression of binary logic, while it's really ternary, and this is what I need.

Comment: Yea but didn't you say that the where(field.not_eq => nil) properly translates to `IS NOT NULL` i might misunderstand you completely but i'm glad you found a solution!

Comment: The solution? I didn't find it, I was still clarifying the question =)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great opportunity to make a github branch :) It's *totally* a feature that should be added to meta_where.